# login_required - login success not redirecting to "next"

Tags: python, django

I am googling for 2 hours now and no sign of success.

after successfull login, I need to redirect user to the page where he was before login, using `next` parameter in the url.

but if i do `print request.GET.get('next')`, i am getting `None` even if i have `next` in the url like `?next=/next-page/` why is this?

my login view.

```
    username = request.POST.get('username_login')
    pwd = request.POST.get('pwd_login')
    user = authenticate(username=_username, password=pwd)        
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            print request.GET.get('next')
            if request.GET.get('next', False):
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('next'))
            else:
                return render_to_response("profil.html",{},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:#user not active
            fail = 'account inactive' 
            return render_to_response("anmelden.html",{'fail':fail},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

i am using django 1.4 and i am using `contrib.auth.login()`. why cannot i redirect to the page?

Comment: You have to decide whether you are using `request.GET` or `request.POST`.

Comment: the good way to do it is to use django url reverse resolvers, pretty easy

Comment: @kroolik, what do you mean? the url has ``?next=/blabla/`` which means it is request.GET, isnot it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using django.contrib.auth.login() that should mean you have simply to override django default login by using LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL for example, you only have to override the views.py if you want to sign up and redirect to login.
so you can override django login urls.py login.html and other.

```
 settings.py:
 LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/' # to redirect to the home after login

urls.py:
urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.auth.views',
    (r'^login/$','login',{'template_name':'registration/login.html'},'login'),
)

login.html :
<div id="main">
{% if form.errors %}
     <ul class="errorlist">
     <li>You entered an invalid username or password</li>
    </ul>       <br/>
      {% endif %}
      <form method="POST" action="{% url "django.contrib.auth.views.login" %}">{% csrf_token %}
        <table summary="login" id="login">
        <caption>Login</caption>
        <tr>
                <td>{{form.username.label_tag}}:</td>
                <td>{{form.username}}</td>          
        </tr>

        <tr>
                <td>{{form.password.label_tag}}:</td>
                <td>{{form.password}}</td>          
        </tr>           
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="right">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>          
        </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}" />
        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: i think, this is irrelevant to what i want. I want to redirect user to the place where he was when he clicked "login"

Comment: OK, i understand that, it a real great idea and i think you can do the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in settings to capture the actual url where the user what before clik on login and after click it should be redirect by there. for sure if you try it like that it should work.